# Dynamic Select Query On Another DB

Tags: database, 8

Is there a straightforward solution to do the dynamic select statements against another database on the same server? I fooled around with attempting to modify the documentation example to no avail.

```
// Create an object of type SelectQuery and directly 
// add extra detail to this query object: a condition, fields and a range
$query = db_select('custom_module_db', 'table_foo')
  ->condition('table_foo.id', 0, '>')
  ->fields(array('id', 'field_1', 'field_2'));

$result = $query->execute();
```

My current database setup looks like this

```
AWS RDS Server 
 ->production drupal database
   ->Drupal Installation Tables
 ->custom module database
   ->Custom Module Tables
```

Clarification the below method works fine against the custom module database without adding a specific settings reference for that particular database.

So was looking to see if I can use the db_select() function in the same way as db_query() without needing to go in and add another database reference.

```
 $data_set = db_query($query='SELECT * FROM custom_module.db.table_foo WHERE ......)
```

Then grabbing the resultset by

```
$results = $this->WeightedAverageFunction($data_set->fetchAll())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add external database name in settings.php(../sites/all/default/settings.php) file of your project. You can set databse in settings.php as follows:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'drupal_db',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '8080',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),

  'external' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'external_db',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '8080',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

And you can directly add your query in files.

Comment: not that its a major inconvenience or a roadblock in my project, but is there a way to do it without adding in the additional database reference? I detailed above how I do it right now without adding that reference. But, what I was really looking for was how to use the db_select() without needing to add another reference in the settings.php file.